# Nginx access log clarification

Tags: nginx

I noticed the below line of log in the nginx access log file. What does it mean?

```
15.23.35.45 - - [19/Feb/2022:07:09:25 +0000] "" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx can produce logs in a variety of customizable formats. To know for sure exactly what fields are what, you should look for the `log_format` directive in your nginx configuration files.  See https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/

It looks like your server is probably configured to produce logs in [combined log format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format). That is a common way that web server logging to be configured.  Both Apache and Nginx can produce very similar looking log files in this format.

In this format fields that are not available to be logged are represented as `-` or `"-"`.  This log entry has very little actual information in it. The pieces that are available:

1. `15.23.35.45` The IP address of the client that made the request
2. `[19/Feb/2022:07:09:25 +0000]` The time and date when the request was made
3. `""` The first line of the request, apparently empty
4. `400` The HTTP status of the response (400 is "bad request", probably because there was no first line of the request)
5. `0` is the size of the response.  (It looks like no response was sent.)

From this we can deduce that the client opened a connection to your web server and sent no request. Nginx returned no response and logged it as a bad request.

As far as the `-` fields go, the first two are related to logged in users. These fields don't have data in this log format in the majority of situations.  The last two fields are the referrer and user-agent which usually get sent by the client, but which were not sent in this case.